# iOS 10 Webkit Play Multiple Videos Inline

Tags: ios, video, safari, webkit

I'd like to use mp4s interspersed with text on my blog, like gifs. iOS 10 now allows the `playsinline` attribute on `video` tags, which works great.

However, when another video comes into the viewport and starts playing it pauses any other video. On the iPad this is confusing because there are often more than one video elements visible.

I've added a click handler to play a video when it is tapped. In this case too, playing one video pauses the others. Is there any way to play more than one video at a time in iOS Safari / Webkit?

Comment: This is related issue?/ Bug 162366 – Allow multiple playing videos on a page with 'autoplay' and 'playsinline' attributes https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162366